# add .js extension to imports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using typescript and want to compile the code down to .js

It works very well. I have this command:

```
"tsc vytic.ts --outDir ./dist --target ES2019"
```

I want to run this code in my browser but i have an problem.

In my code i have imports like this:

```
import { parseHTML } from "./helpers/parser";
import { Reactivity } from "./helpers/reactivity";
```

My browser cannot find it because it has no `.js` extension on the end

Can i configurate typescript to add .js on the end? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you will need to bundle your javascript files for browser using Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: this actually helped me out https://github.com/Zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension/